# creating many matrix from one matrix with looping?

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a square matrix `M` with 25x25 dimension. 
Then I want to create 25 matrices as follow:

- the first matrix is matrix `M` without the first row and first column,
- the second matrix is matrix `M` without the second row and second column, - ... so on until 25th matrix.

Comment: Generally you provide some demonstrated attempt of your own.  Respectfully, this is not a coding service.  Provide a specific problem and we can help.

Comment: It might also be helpful (and improve the usefulness of the answers *to you* as well as others) if you can give a little bit of context/reasons why you want to solve this particular problem ... (is this homework? if so, it's extra-important to explain what you tried and where you got stuck)

Comment: `lapply(1:25, function(i) M[-i, -i])`

Comment: i am  so sorry, to be honest i have to create quite complex function in r for my researh. I tried my best to solve it but i got stuck at this moment. i just ask a few question that maybe it's not difficult for you all. pardon me if i made some mistake, thanks for your great advice. thank you @jogo for your help.

Comment: @jogo, post as answer?

Answer (score 2):

this little snippet will do:

```
lapply(1:25, function(i) M[-i, -i])
```